# Counting notification by channel in Installation table - Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I wonder if there's any way to counting notification by channel in user Installation table. For example if user subscribed to : channel_1, channel_2, channel_3 , when user receive notification for chennel_x, counter for this channel automatically increment value?

What is best practice for counting new notification for users channel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built into Installations that allows for this, but you could accomplish this:

1. Add a column for each channel in the Installation table, and increment it when a push is sent.